# why when using console.log() on a variable created afterwards but in another script tag i get an error instead of logging 'undefined' in the console?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, console.log, hoisting

why would this code snippet give an error in the console "**Uncaught ReferenceError: x is not defined**"

```
<body>
    <script>
        console.log(x);
    </script>
    
    <script>
        var x = 10;
    </script>
</body>
```

while this one logs "**undefined**"?

```
<body>
    <script>
        console.log(x);
        var x = 10;
    </script>
</body>
```

i was trying to learn about variable declaration and variable scopes. and expected that hoisting was going to happen because the whole code is in the same page. but because the console.log() is seperated in another scirpt tag i got an error instead of just logging 'undefined' in the console.

Comment: Research [variable hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting)

Comment: "*because the `console.log()` is seperated in another scirpt tag i got an error instead of [hoisting]*" - seems like you have answered your own question

Comment: The actual answer is not about variable hoisting in particular. You have a timing error - the second script tag has not been processed (parsed and executed) before the first script is executed. The JavaScript engine knows _nothing_ about file level declarations within the second script when compiling and executing the first script.

Comment: The article for [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) on MDN has been updated since this question. Hopefully changes made to the`Description` and `Hoisting` sections (the latter with a note covering this title of the question) now better answer your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var` is hoisted, that means it's accessible right in the beginning of the scope where it's defined even the declaration line could be in the end of the scope. If you access the var before it's declaration it's `undefined` because you still need to execute the declaration with possible initialization this variable to particular value.
So your second example works that way.

Read about hoisting here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting

But in your first example 2 `<scripts>` have 2 different scopes, so the var basically doesn't exists in the first script thus the error `not defined`.

Read about `var` and its scope here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var

**IMPORTANT**
I strongly advocate against using `var`. Use `const` and `let` instead. Using `var` with hoisting leads to bugs which sometimes are very hard to debug and fix. If you need using only `var` in your production, just downgrade your code with esbuild for example to the appropriate older version of JS.

Interestingly enough, `const` and `let` are *kinda* hoisted also, but accessing them in the hoisted state leads to a runtime error (that's called a temporal dead zone), that's why they are more safe because you get an error immediately opposed to `var` hoisted silently and thus leaving you with a potential bug you don't know about.

About the temporal dead zone:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz

```html
<body>
    <script>
        console.log(x);
        const x = 10;
    </script>
</body>
```

An interesting part: the 2 `<script>`s are executed in order of appearance but if you change the order by deferring it (executing after DOM is built) with `type="module"` then you get the variable defined. This is only way to defer an inline script since `defer` wouldn't work:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

```html
<body>
    <script type="module">
        console.log(x);
    </script>
    
    <script>
        var x = 10;
    </script>
</body>
```